# Como actualizar el valor de una secuencia en Firebird 2.5?

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

estoy tratando de actualizar el valor de un generador de id. Al intentar actualizar la secuencia mediante un script me arroja un error.

Este es el script que intento ejecutar

```
set term ^ ;
execute block
as
    declare variable codigo integer ;
begin
    select first 1 (peo2.codigo+1)
    from presupuestosestadosoportunidad peo2
    order by peo2.codigo desc
    into :codigo;

    execute statement
        'ALTER SEQUENCE GEN_PRESUPESTADOSOPORTUNIDAD RESTART WITH ' + cast(codigo as varchar(10))+ ';';
end ^
commit work ^
set term ; ^
```

Este es el error que me tira:

> can't format message 13:198 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found.
> arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation.
> string right truncation.
> At block line: 12, col: 1.

No logro entender porque me tira ese error. Tengo entendido que para actualizar una secuencia, el valor que se pasa tiene que ser una constante. Es por esto que convierto el valor del codigo a varchar. El valor que deberia estar teniendo el id es aproximadaamente 453788.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiero que te asegures cuál es el valor que estás obteniendo en la consulta que haces.

He adaptado el código para correr en firebird 3.0 (no tengo 2.5 a mano ahora), y al sobrepasar los 10 dígitos el valor de la secuencia, obtengo un error similar al tuyo (solo que yo si tengo el archivo de mensajes).

Mi código es:

```
set term ^;
execute block
as
  declare variable codigo integer;
  declare variable sql varchar(10000);
begin
  codigo = 1234567890;
  sql = 'ALTER SEQUENCE GEN_PRESUPESTADOSOPORTUNIDAD RESTART WITH ' || cast(codigo as varchar(50)) || ';';
  execute statement sql;
end 
^
set term ;^
```

Este se ejecuta sin problemas, sin embargo si cambio a:

```
codigo = 12345678901;
```

Obtengo esto:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 22003
arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation
-numeric value is out of range
-At block line: 6, col: 3
```

Lo curioso es que la línea 6 no es la de la ejecución del `alter sequence`, sino la asignación del valor a la variable. Si cambio el tipo de dato por bigint, el error nuevamente desaparece, de hecho, el siguiente código se ejecuta sin problemas.

```
set term ^;

execute block
as
  declare variable codigo bigint;
  declare variable sql varchar(10000);
begin
  codigo = 123456789012345678;
  sql = 'ALTER SEQUENCE GEN_PRESUPESTADOSOPORTUNIDAD RESTART WITH ' || cast(codigo as varchar(50)) || ';';
  execute statement sql;
end 
^

set term ;^
```

Una última cosa: me llama la atención que hagas un `select first 1 xxx order by xxx desc`, sospecho que el plan para esta versión equivalente podría ser más eficiente:

```
select max(talcosa) + 1 from tabla
```

Siempre que exista un índice por la columna `talcosa`.